# md-virtual-repeat height is adjusting when window resize on second time

Tags: angularjs

[image]

I am using `md-virtual-repeat` in the sidenav md-list. It's height is coming properly for the first time. When I close it and open it again it's height is becoming half. But if I resize window its height is coming properly again.

[image]

Comment: It might happen if you wrote custom styling for `md-virtual-repeat` container. Please post your example in Codepen

Comment: @MaximShoustin I am using                                                                    `<md-virtual-repeat-container ng-if="category.name == categoryName && category.id == null" style="height:{{height}}" ng-cloak> `                                                                 `$scope.height = ($scope.subCategories.length * 3) + 300 +'px';' I am adding height using $scope.height variable.